# Export all interfaces in directory for better import statements / autofill

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, module

What is the best way to elegantly export all interfaces / enums in a directory?

### Case

Take the following:

```
import { TimeFrame } from '@types/shared/TimeFrame'
import { Address } from '@types/shared/Address'
import { Contact } from '@types/shared/Contact'

import { ApiBaseParameters } from '@types/api/BaseParams'
import { MailApiQueryParameters } from '@types/api/MailApiQueryParameters'
import { MailApiBodyParameters } from '@types/api/MailApiBodyParameters'
import { MailApiResponse } from '@types/api/MailApiResponse'
import ...

import { StateEnums } from '@enums/States'
import { CountryEnums } from '@enums/CountryEnums'
```

Can we make it something easier to use? For example...

```
import * as Type from '@types'
import * as Enum from '@enums'

or

import { 
 TimeFrame, Address, Contact,
 ApiBaseParameters,
 MailApiQueryParameters, MailApiBodyParameters, MailApiResponse,
 ...
} from '@types'
import { StateEnums, CountryEnums } from '@enums'
```

Each .ts file contains something like

```
interface TimeFrame {
 start_time: string
 end_time: string
}
export { TimeFrame }
```

### Issue

Our interfaces are growing quickly and it's taking too much time to track down what is included and where to find all the interfaces / enums.

Eventually, this may become a packaging and we want it so that when another developer installs the package, they can easily see all the interfaces included.

I know it would be possible to add in each directory an index.ts file with `export * from './fileName` but then you have to hope all contributors remember to do this for every file.

### Question

Is there a better approach to this? Is it possible to automatically or programatically create an index.ts file that exports all exports in the directory to...

- Slim the import statements in other files.
- Reduce effort of others writing their own interface when it already exists
- Maybe get some autofill options like `Type.Ma....` and then see all the types beginning with "Ma"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries that generates index.ts files automatically. And allows you to configure them. Like [Barrelsby](https://github.com/bencoveney/barrelsby), [Create-ts-index](https://github.com/imjuni/create-ts-index).
Create-ts-index also has a library that allows you to configure it programmatically.

What you can do with them is add a post build step. Use their CLI or API to generate index.ts files.

- Reduce effort of others writing their own interface when it already
  exists
- Maybe get some autofill options like Type.Ma.... and then see
  all the types beginning with "Ma"?

For those you may seek for IDE plugins. Some jetBrains producst (Webstorm, IntelliJ and Resharper for Visual Studio) already does these kind of things.

For suggestion part Visual Studio Code has [Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) plugin. When you type a `Type` that suggests you among existing types and when you select auto imports it. And there a bunch of plugins similar to it.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes the hardest part is finding the right keyword to search.